# How can you use JasperReport Viewer in your Web App?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've manage to use the JasperReport Viewer in my desktop app, but I was curious if I can do the same in my web application with all the print properties and buttons available.

Is this possible? Is there a Web Based Print Preview for Jasper Reports?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to install jasper server and upload your report on jasperserver after that you can bind your report in web application with visualize.js.